# Time value cached in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following service providing me with an array mapping month/week/today to a time.

```
module Admin
  class TimeService
    INTERVAL_TIME = [
      { :id => "month", :from => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month },
      { :id => "week", :from => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week },
      { :id => "today", :from => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day }
    ]
  end
end
```

In my controller params[:id] is passed, holding either "month"/"week"/"today", to index method.

```
class TimeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @entry = TimeService::INTERVAL_TIME.find { 
                                 |item| item[:id] == params[:time_id] }
  end
end
```

Then I use the entry[:from] in my view. Everything works fine in development, but in production the value shown for "today" is usually a couple days back. I guess there might be some caching going on, but I have only been able to find people having trouble with scopes being cached. Anyone know how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, the `:from` keys will have the values as calculated at them moment your class is loaded, once.

In development mode, the classes are reloaded that's why you don't see the "cached" values there.

The `:from` keys in your constant should have lambdas as values in order to calculate the values each time they are accessed (you'll have to change the way you access their values since they'll be lambdas).